# Detect bot running via xvbf + Chrome under puppeteer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xvfb

Is it possible to detect in javascript that HTTP request came from system where Chrome is running with xvbf under puppeteer?

So in this case bot browser is headfull

Comment: May we know what your use case for this is? ([XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/))

Comment: Looks like somebody sends requests to our site using Chrome under xvbf.    
We need to detect and block this requests